# How do I determine the value of a generic parameter on my class instance

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a marker interface defined as

```
public interface IExtender<T>
{
}
```

I have a class that implements IExtender

```
public class UserExtender : IExtender<User>
```

At runtime I recieve the UserExtender type as a parameter to my evaluating method

```
public Type Evaluate(Type type) // type == typeof(UserExtender)
```

How do I make my Evaluate method return

```
typeof(User)
```

based on the runtime evaluation. I am sure reflection is involved but I can't seem to crack it.

(I was unsure how to word this question. I hope it is clear enough.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went this way based on some of the tidbits provided. It could be made more robust to handle multiple generic arguments on the interface.... but I didn't need it to ;)

```
private static Type SafeGetSingleGenericParameter(Type type, Type interfaceType)
{
    if (!interfaceType.IsGenericType || interfaceType.GetGenericArguments().Count() != 1)
        return type;

    foreach (Type baseInterface in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (baseInterface.IsGenericType &&
                baseInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
        {
            return baseInterface.GetGenericArguments().Single();
        }
    }

    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of doing what you describe in the MSDN documentation for the [GetGenericTypeDefinition method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition).  It uses the [GetGenericArguments method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments).

```
Type[] typeArguments = t.GetGenericArguments();
Console.WriteLine("\tList type arguments ({0}):", typeArguments.Length);
foreach (Type tParam in typeArguments)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", tParam);
}
```

In your example I think you would want to replace `t` with `this`.  If that doesn't work directly you may need to do something with the [GetInterfaces method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces) to enumerate the current interfaces on your type and then `GetGenericArguments()` from the interface type.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question completely differently than the other answers.

If the evaluate signature can be changed to:

```cs
public Type Evaluate<T>(IExtender<T> it)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

This doesn't require the calling code to change, but does require the parameter to be of type `IExtender<T>`, however you can easily get at the type `T` :

```cs
// ** compiled and tested    
UserExtender ue = new UserExtender();
Type t = Evaluate(ue);
```

Certainly it's not as generic as something just taking a `Type` parameter, but this is a different take on the problem. Also note that there are [Security Considerations for Reflection [msdn]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-considerations-for-reflection)